# Get all values of object with JSON

Tags: python, json

I wouldlike to get all summonername and leaguePoints from a JSON file in python.

Json file :

```
{
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "summonerName": "TheUnshackIedone",
        "hotStreak": true,
        "wins": 716,
        "veteran": true,
        "losses": 587,
        "rank": "I",
        "tier": "CHALLENGER",
        "inactive": false,
        "freshBlood": false,
        "leagueId": "65ebcd4f-368c-30f6-a635-976beb0e1a8c",
        "summonerId": "D4tAkhItmCDY6R8XsZXGtVtgukEq8MAONe1mlSDOL4CQxQQ",
        "leaguePoints": 1436
    },
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "summonerName": "waoedsjad",
        "hotStreak": false,
        "wins": 352,
        "veteran": true,
        "losses": 197,
        "rank": "I",
        "tier": "CHALLENGER",
        "inactive": false,
        "freshBlood": false,
        "leagueId": "65ebcd4f-368c-30f6-a635-976beb0e1a8c",
        "summonerId": "SwMmXPPk4VV1ThMOm5vZZDJnkuPyiP2S37iPfAHHZ6_5G5yp",
        "leaguePoints": 1389
    },
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "summonerName": "FNC Bwipo",
        "hotStreak": false,
        "wins": 537,
        "veteran": true,
        "losses": 387,
        "rank": "I",
        "tier": "CHALLENGER",
        "inactive": false,
        "freshBlood": false,
        "leagueId": "65ebcd4f-368c-30f6-a635-976beb0e1a8c",
        "summonerId": "TpMdwXDCPmCAZgUtI1cjoXSL6WFUe9QFaIiTLtbivnC8RPs",
        "leaguePoints": 1323
    },
```

I start to do this but I don't understand how to get all data like that :

TheUnshackIedone
1436

waoedsjad
1389

FNC Bwipo
1323

Here example for 3 pseudos but if I have 100, 1000 or more ? Do I need to use loop ? or it exist another way ?

My python file :

```
def ClassementRank():
    responseJSON = requestRank()

    print(responseJSON[0]['summonerName'])
    print(responseJSON[0]['tier'])
    print(responseJSON[0]['leaguePoints'], "lp")
```

Thansk for any help !

Comment: Yes, you can use a for loop of course. Where are you stuck?

Comment: You probably have to use a loop. A fancier and probably faster way would be a list comprehension.

Comment: is the json file correct? I doubt it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for loop`:

```
def ClassementRank():
    responseJSON = requestRank()
    for entry in responseJSON:
        print(entry['summonerName'])
        print(entry['tier'])
        print(entry['leaguePoints'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop and store it in a list by :

```
    contents = [{
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "summonerName": "TheUnshackIedone",
        "hotStreak": True,
        "wins": 716,
        "veteran": True,
        "losses": 587,
        "rank": "I",
        "tier": "CHALLENGER",
        "inactive": False,
        "freshBlood": False,
        "leagueId": "65ebcd4f-368c-30f6-a635-976beb0e1a8c",
        "summonerId": "D4tAkhItmCDY6R8XsZXGtVtgukEq8MAONe1mlSDOL4CQxQQ",
        "leaguePoints": 1436
    },
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "summonerName": "waoedsjad",
        "hotStreak": False,
        "wins": 352,
        "veteran": True,
        "losses": 197,
        "rank": "I",
        "tier": "CHALLENGER",
        "inactive": False,
        "freshBlood": False,
        "leagueId": "65ebcd4f-368c-30f6-a635-976beb0e1a8c",
        "summonerId": "SwMmXPPk4VV1ThMOm5vZZDJnkuPyiP2S37iPfAHHZ6_5G5yp",
        "leaguePoints": 1389
    },
    {
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "summonerName": "FNC Bwipo",
        "hotStreak": False,
        "wins": 537,
        "veteran": True,
        "losses": 387,
        "rank": "I",
        "tier": "CHALLENGER",
        "inactive": False,
        "freshBlood": False,
        "leagueId": "65ebcd4f-368c-30f6-a635-976beb0e1a8c",
        "summonerId": "TpMdwXDCPmCAZgUtI1cjoXSL6WFUe9QFaIiTLtbivnC8RPs",
        "leaguePoints": 1323
    }]

li = [{item.get('summonerName'),item.get('leaguePoints')} for item in contents]
print(li)
```

Here is working screenshot :

[image: Working Demo]